# Send email from PHP and catch the autoresponses

Tags: php, email, dns

I'm sending emails using a PHP script and class.phpmailer.php.
I need to be able to 'catch' bounces and auto-responses. I'm able to catch the bounces already. I created an alias that redirects bounces to a php script, and I parse the email there. I include some information in the original email in the headers, so I can know which emails bounced.

The same logic should work for the auto-responses, I think the problem is that the email are not getting to the server. I already have a reverse DNS configured, pointing to the server IP address.

This is part of how I send an email:

```
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->From = $fromAddr;
            $mail->Sender = $sender; 
            $mail->FromName = $fromName;
            $mail->AddAddress($email);
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
```

the I add the headers, for example:

```
            $mail->AddCustomHeader($mail->HeaderLine("From", $fromAddr));
            $mail->AddCustomHeader($mail->HeaderLine("Subject", $subject));

            $mail->AddCustomHeader($mail->HeaderLine("Company-State", "Florida"));
            $mail->AddCustomHeader($mail->HeaderLine("Company-Country", "USA"));

            $mail->AddCustomHeader($mail->HeaderLine("From", $fromAddr));
            $mail->AddCustomHeader($mail->HeaderLine("Reply-To", $fromAddr));
```

My RDNS is something like: mail2.mydomain.com. The bounces are going to "www-data".
What should I add and where? something like www-data@mail2.mydomain.com?

Tks!

Comment: shouldn't autoresponses go to the same reply-to email address ? Also, check the User-Agent of the email header.

Comment: sendmail (or whatever mailer is actually handling the outgoing stuff) may not be honoring the From you're setting and forcing it to be that of the owning process, which'd be your webserver www-data. You may have to investigate how to force the smtp server to not do that, e.g. the sendmail `-f` parameter.

Comment: Bounces (something went wrong on servers) should go to `$sender`, replies (mail arrives, there's just a machine of human replying) to `$fromAddr` in your example, and they are not the same thing. (See the `$additional_parameters` section in the [mail](http://www.php.net/mail) manual)